# ida pro doesn't show complete disassambled export function?

Tags: c++, disassembly, dllexport, ida, win32-process

Please excuse my newbie question but when I tried exporting a function in the header using

```
__declspec(dllexport) void testfunction(double i);
```

and declared the function in the .cpp file like this

```
void testfunction(double i) {
   for (int k = 0; k<10; k++) {
        double j = 0.1;
   }    
}
```

I only see this for the function after disassembling the .exe file using IDA pro:

```
.text:00401130 ; void __cdecl testfunction(double)
.text:00401130                 public ?testfunction@@YAXN@Z
.text:00401130 ?testfunction@@YAXN@Z proc near         ; DATA XREF: .rdata:off_40BE88o
.text:00401130                 jmp     dword_40C000
.text:00401130 ?testfunction@@YAXN@Z endp
```

Below I have provided the location of dword_40C000

```
.data:0040C000 ; Section 3. (virtual address 0000C000)
.data:0040C000 ; Virtual size                  : 000004A0 (   1184.)
.data:0040C000 ; Section size in file          : 00000200 (    512.)
.data:0040C000 ; Offset to raw data for section: 0000B200
.data:0040C000 ; Flags C0000040: Data Readable Writable
.data:0040C000 ; Alignment     : default
.data:0040C000 ; ===========================================================================
.data:0040C000
.data:0040C000 ; Segment type: Pure data
.data:0040C000 ; Segment permissions: Read/Write
.data:0040C000 _data           segment para public 'DATA' use32
.data:0040C000                 assume cs:_data
.data:0040C000                 ;org 40C000h
.data:0040C000 dword_40C000    dd 6000001h             ; DATA XREF: testfunction(double)r
.data:0040C004                 align 10h
.data:0040C010                 db    2
.data:0040C011                 db    0
.data:0040C012                 db    0
.data:0040C013                 db    0
.data:0040C014                 db    2
.data:0040C015                 db    0
.data:0040C016                 db    0
.data:0040C017                 db    0
.data:0040C018 dword_40C018    dd 6000003h             ; DATA XREF: .text:004011A0r
.data:0040C01C dword_40C01C    dd 6000004h             ; DATA XREF: .text:004011D0r
.data:0040C020 dword_40C020    dd 6000005h             ; DATA XREF: .text:00401200r
...
```

Shouldn't there be more code since I have a for loop and some other stuff? Where is the actual code?

Comment: Its probably been optimised away as it does nothing

Comment: @MikeVine: I see, could you provide an answer on how to turn off optimization for visual studio 2010? Edit: It seems optimization has been turned off according to the configuration menu...

Comment: Oh and please show us the code where the jumps points to. I think thats the actuall problems here, as you are inspecting the file linking against the .dll. Dynamical linkage is implemented by jumps (under windows).

Comment: @Paranaix: Hi I have provided where the code jumped to.

Comment: Ah I dont like the IDA syntax. Well it is like I  said, your OS (windows) writes the address of the real function location to `dword_40C000` once it loaded the module (.dll file). So when the disassembled function is called, it actually jumps to the real function contained in the loaded module. This is called dynamic linking.

Comment: Perhaps this is only the listing of the export table, and not the actual function?

Comment: @Paranaix: I didn't use any dll. I started a new .exe using the form application option from VS2010 and declared this function in the header and .cpp file. Where does dynamic linking come from?

Comment: @Mark Why do you declare your function using `__declspec(dllexport)` then?

Comment: @Paranaix: I wanted to located the function's location more easily in IDA since there is a nice export window of the functions that are being exported. Initially I used a dll file for experiment and used __declspec(dllexport) but the disassembled output was the same as exe.

Comment: @Mark Well compiling the above code without optimization using MSVC gives me the expected asm: http://pastebin.com/wYWrqvPx . I really believe your compilation or linkage is somehow messed up.

Comment: @Paranaix it seems after removing __declspec(dllexport) i could see the code for the actual function. Before I could only see the exported table?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using C++/CLI. I think the 6000001 is the managed method's token, it will be replaced by the address of the JITted code at runtime.

Compile your binary for native x86 to see machine code.